# Facing Problem in encoding array of dictionary to JSON

Tags: json, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary

In POST request I have to send following JSON data

```
{
    "users": [{"userid": 16, "meetAt":"Some place (College/trip etc)", "showFields": "11111111000"}, {"userid": 17, "meetAt":"Some place (College/trip etc)", "showFields": "11111111001"}]
}
```

I am trying

```
static func linkRequestBody(userDetails: ScannedContact) -> Any
{

    let jsonToRegistrer =  [["userid":userDetails.id, "meetAt":"Defalut Test Location at", "showFields":userDetails.showFields]];
    return jsonToRegistrer;
}
```

I can see in debugger that `userDetails.id` and `userDetails.showFields` have valid value but still it fails.

ERROR:

```
{"":["The input was not valid."]}
```

Comment: Fails? Where exactly? Also `jsonToRegistrer` is strange because if you return a Dictionary, not Any, also you didn't put `"users"`. It should be at least `let jsonToRegistrer =  ["user": [["userid":userDetails.id, "meetAt":"Defalut Test Location at", "showFields":userDetails.showFields]]];` And then I hope you use AFNetworking or any other lib that already calls `NSJSONSerialization` because it's not currently JSON.

Comment: @Larme - you are correct. I just found this. Also I update the Error in OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's your target format:

```
{
    "users": [{
        "userid": 16,
        "meetAt": "Some place (College/trip etc)",
        "showFields": "11111111000"
    }, {
        "userid": 17,
        "meetAt": "Some place (College/trip etc)",
        "showFields": "11111111001"
    }]
}
```

After calling `JSONSerialization` on it (or if your code accept a Dictionary/Array and do the translation itself):

```
let jsonToRegistrer =  [["userid":userDetails.id, "meetAt":"Defalut Test Location at", "showFields":userDetails.showFields]];
```

Should represent that:

```
[{
    "userid": 16,
    "meetAt": "Defalut Test Location at",
    "showFields": "11111111000"
}]
```

You see the issue? Your version is an `Array` and the target one is a `Dictionary` and you are so missing the `users` key.

To fix it:

```
let jsonToRegistrer =  ["user": [["userid":userDetails.id, "meetAt":"Defalut Test Location at", "showFields":userDetails.showFields]]];
```

You can also not write it in one line to be clearer:

```
let jsonToRegistrer = ["user": [
                                 ["userid": userDetails.id,
                                  "meetAt": "Defalut Test Location at",
                                  "showFields": userDetails.showFields]
                                ]
                        ];
```

So the issue is that your version didn't have the same format at the one needed.

To see what's your version rendered in JSON you can use:

```
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonToRegistrer, options: .prettyPrinted)
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8) //Note it's a force unwrap but just to debug, avoid using force unwrap
print("jsonString: \(jsonString)")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would personally avoid the problem by using struct thant implements Codable. As you don't have any value of type Any nor recursive field, this should work very easily

```
struct Users: Codable {
    var users: [User]
}

struct User: Codable {
    let userid: Int
    let meetAt: String
    let showFields: String
}
```

Then you just have to bind `User` in `Users.users` can encode it easily doing

```
do {
    let json = try? JSONEncoder().encode(Users)
} catch { // whatever you want }
```

[This article](https://hackernoon.com/everything-about-codable-in-swift-4-97d0e18a2999) might help you to understand better Codable protocol.
Hope it helps !